# Save a remote server (ssh) connection including password on Mac Terminal

Tags: ssh, terminal.app

Can I save an SSH connection similar to the answer to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/76193/how-to-create-an-ssh-connection-terminal-shortcut-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard) question but including the password?

Answer (score 1):

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/87956/can-you-set-passwords-in-ssh-config-to-allow-automatic-login

However, I recommend just using a pubkey and specifying `IdentityFile` in `.ssh/config`

One can be generated using `ssh-keygen` if you don't have one / don't want to share it with your other logins.  Then you can use `ssh-copy-id` to put it on the remote server.  Keeping a password in plaintext is not recommended for security reasons.